# Let window grow based on one control's size but not the other's

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a window containign a textblock with variable text and a stackpanel which contains a variable amount of buttons.
[image: My Window]
How can I let the window grow in width (horizontally), when the stackpanel grows in width but let the text always adapt to the available width (not grow the window in width when the text gets longer).

I've tried some combinations with and without Width="Auto" / VerticalAlign="Stretch" / TextWrapping etc. but I only get the window to grow if either one (text length / stackpanel children) grow in width.

I want the text to wrap based on the width of the window which shall be based on the width of the stackpanel. XAML only would be nice.

**Edit**

As requested some stripped-down markup to reproduce the issue:

```
<Window 
    Width="500" 
    Height="225" 
    MinWidth="500" 
    MinHeight="225"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Text should adapt to the available width but not grow the window. Instead it should scroll vertically -->
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Margin="15" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto">...Some Binding...</TextBlock>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <!-- Should be as wide as it needs to be, growing the window in width if neccessary -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonStackPanel" Grid.Row="1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
            ...Some Buttons...
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Edit 2**
The window is supposed to have a MinWidth of 500, if there's only one button in the stackpanel, it should still stretch full width (500px).

**Edit 3 - Some more pictures**

Correct - Text is short, only one button -> MinWidth 500
[image]
Wrong - Text is long and should wrap at the MinWidth of 500 because only the Stackpanel should be allowed to grow the window in width
[image]
Correct - Short text but stack panel grows the window
[image]

Comment: Please post some XAML markup that can be used to reproduce your issue. How wide is the TextBlock supposed to be?

Comment: @mm8 as I wrote in the second and fourth paragraph, as wide as it can be. But it should not grow the window. Only the stackpanel should grow the window's width.

Comment: @mm8 markup added

Comment: You can bind `MaximumWidth` of one control to `ActualWidth` of another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to bind the `Width` of the `Window` to the outer `Grid`'s `Width` (as Mighty Badaboom suggested) and the `Width` of the `ScrollViewer` to the `ActualWidth` of your `StackPanel`.

Here is how you can achieve it:

```
<Window SizeChanged="MainWindow_OnSizeChanged" Height="225" SizeToContent="Width" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid Name="OuterGrid" MinWidth="500">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Margin="15" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto">...Some Binding...</TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue">
        <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto">
            ...Some Buttons...
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And code behind:

```
private void MainWindow_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.WidthChanged)
        OuterGrid.Width = Panel.ActualWidth;
}
```

EDIT: Added an outer `StackPanel` to support Stretching & blue Background requirement.

EDIT 2: It seems that you can't achieve the behavior you're describing with only XAML. Although the fix is a few lines of code away.

Comment: Good idea but I would suggest binding the window width to the outer `Grid` instead of the `StackPanel`because you could get in trouble when adding margins.

Comment: I need the stack panel to have HorizontalAlignment=Stretch and this somehow leads to infinite width :D

Comment: @SlapY Yep, this leads to infinite width. Why you need it?

Comment: @GeorgeChond It's basically a message box and the lower part should have a blue background. It therefore needs to stretch.

Comment: Hmm, what the blue background has to do with the stretching? can you update your question with an example please?

Comment: @GeorgeChond Actually the original window is a bit more complex. I need the bottom row (StackPanel in this example) to be full width of the window and feature a blue background. Your suggestion does not stretch the whole width.

Comment: @SlapY You can use an outer StackPanel for that purpose. I updated my answer.

Comment: @GeorgeChond Thanks, I'm trying it. Meanwhile I added some more pictures above to clarify. There's actually already a border with blue background around the stack panel

Comment: @SlapY It seems that you can't achieve that exact behavior without some code behind. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yep! That's it, thanks. I just had to factor in the MinWidth: OuterGrid.Width = Math.Max(this.MinWidth, ButtonStackPanel.ActualWidth);

Comment: Like most of the `outer.Width = inner.ActualWidth` approaches, this will work for growing data, but the size will not shrink if a button is removed, unless some different size change is triggering the event. So as long as the layout is not dynamically shrinking, this will work fine, otherwise be more careful regarding the event source for `SizeChanged`.

Answer (score 2):

You could write your own custom control and override measure/arrange in a way that width and height is dominated by different child elements. Note I'm cheating a bit here by just using the first two children of a panel and giving them a different meaning based on your question, without even checking for valid child indices first etc.:

```
public class SizeAwareControl : Panel
{
    private UIElement HeightDeterminingContent
    {
        get { return InternalChildren[0]; }
    }
    private UIElement WidthDeterminingContent
    {
        get { return InternalChildren[1]; }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size result = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);

        WidthDeterminingContent.Measure(result);

        result.Width = WidthDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Width;

        HeightDeterminingContent.Measure(result);

        result.Height = WidthDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Height + HeightDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Height;

        return result;
    }
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds)
    {
        HeightDeterminingContent.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, WidthDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Width, HeightDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Height));
        WidthDeterminingContent.Arrange(new Rect(0, HeightDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Height, WidthDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Width, WidthDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Height));
        return new Size(WidthDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Width, WidthDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Height + HeightDeterminingContent.DesiredSize.Height);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
<local:SizeAwareControl>
    <!-- First child determines the height -->
    <ScrollViewer Margin="15" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="600">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto">...Some Binding...</TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <!-- Second child determines the width -->
    <StackPanel x:Name="ButtonStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="500">
        <Button Width="100" Content="..." Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        <Button Width="100" Content="..."/>
        <Button Width="100" Content="..."/>
    </StackPanel>
</local:SizeAwareControl>
```

This is just a starting point - you may need some more detailed logic to determine good width and height values. The `MaxHeight` on the first child enables scrolling for long text (instead of growing a very tall window) and the `MinWidth` on the second child ensures width for a low amount of buttons.